# Taskmaster's fighting style

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow

In the movie *Black Widow* there is an enemy fighter called Taskmaster. It is said that Taskmaster can mimic the fighting style of everyone they see. I noticed them mimicking Captain America's shield fighting style, Winter Soldier's knife fighting abilities, and Black Widow's fighting style. Has Taskmaster displayed in the movie any other styles based on different characters from the Marvel Cinematic Universe? And does this mean that they already fought with the Winter Soldier and Captain America, or could they have learned it from watching them on video?

Comment: From watching videos most likely, you see this in the film. Others noticed: Spider-Man, Black Panther.

Comment: We also see him using a bow like Hawkeye

Comment: So I wasn't paying as much attention to their fighting style as I thought I did, I'll have to watch it again and try to see Spider-Man, Black Panther and Hawkeye.